# HS3 (Harry Styles) Album

Tags: album, singers, album-title, one-direction, harry-styles

Do we know what [Harry Styles'](https://g.co/kgs/GG97Mk) 3rd Album will be called, when it will be released, or what songs it will contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 23rd March 2022, [Harry Styles confirmed on his social media](https://twitter.com/Harry_Styles/status/1506662230892314634?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1506662230892314634%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_c10&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublish.twitter.com%2F%3Fquery%3Dhttps3A2F2Ftwitter.com2FHarry_Styles2Fstatus2F1506662230892314634widget%3DTweet) that his 3rd album, Harry's House, was to be released on May 20th 2022.

We still do not know what songs will be on there, but on the [Harry's House Twitter](https://twitter.com/youarehome), there have been (potential) lyrics posted.

---

[**As It Was**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5v3kku4y6Q) was released 31/03/22

Answer (score 2):

I know about [this PopBuzz article](https://www.popbuzz.com/music/artists/harry-styles/news/new-album-hs3-release-date-tracklist/), but this was written 1 month ago...

---

> "Harry has just wrapped the US leg of Fine Line's tour and fans think that he's dropping hints that a new era is upon us"

---

> "As it stands, Harry is yet to state anything official about when he will release new music but there were two years between the releases of his first album and Fine Line, and it's now been two years since Fine Line came out"

---

> "We know nothing about the HS3 songs just yet but we shall update you as soon as we do"