# How many songs will Harry's House have?

Tags: album, one-direction, harry-styles

As a follow-up from [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/hs3-harry-styles-album), do we know how many songs Harry's House will contain?

1. Harry Styles - 10 Songs
2. Fine Line - 12 Songs
3. Harry's House - ??? Songs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This news article](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/magazines/panache/harry-styles-announces-his-third-album-harrys-house-it-will-include-13-songs-to-release-on-may-20/articleshow/90431318.cms) explains that it shall have 13 songs.